# How to open all numbers from WhatsApp directly in Truecaller?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, truecaller

I'm part of some WhatsApp groups and there are people whom I know but am unable to map them to those phone contacts which do not show anything but blank profile photos and no name. Asking everyone will be too much work.

Is there any way to directly open the contacts in Truecaller instead of the default Android app?

Comment: Aren't there names present in the group information?

Comment: @beeshyams Nope, I only see numbers. They are not my contacts so.

Comment: What i do in your case is, i copy the contact to true caller and then i see the name. I don't see a more direct way of doing this

Comment: @Abochur isn't this too much work? This is crazy frustrating man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to get people's details for WhatsApp messages is to use **Auto-Search** in Truecaller by allowing *Notification access* to Truecaller.

Go to **Truecaller->Settings->General->Auto-Search** and switch **Messaging apps** to ON.

[image: Truecaller screen shot]

And whenever you get a message from person who is not in your contact list, you will get a notification like:

[image: notification screen shot]

This also works for messages from groups too, but you will get notified only when someone sends you a message (can't fetch all unknown contacts from the WhatsApp group).

*Allowing notification access is a dangerous permission*.

> Truecaller will be able to read all notifications, including personal information such as contact names and the text of messages you receive. It will also be able to dismiss notifications or trigger action buttons they contain. This will also give the app the ability to turn Do Not Disturb on or off and change related settings.

P.S. WhatsApp does show names (which the user has set in his WhatsApp profile) in *group info* for each person.

Comment: I needed Copied numbers also to be enabled. Anyways thanks for this!

Comment: Yes, that will immediately pop up information of any copied number.

Comment: Yup, the copy number option makes life a little easier. But it's still too much work. Can't WhatsApp by default integrate TrueCaller into it?

Comment: I don't think that's gonna happen. Since they both are completely different apps.

Comment: Since WhatsApp Groups are meant to "keep in touch with the groups of people that matter the most, like your family or coworkers" so they don't assume that unknown people are bunched into Groups.